# add three triptych side by side

Tags: 7, theming

i have made a custom theme "Custom_stark" and 
made changes into .info file and added the triptychs

```
regions[triptych_first] = Triptych first
regions[triptych_middle] = Triptych middle
regions[triptych_last] = Triptych last
```

in Custom_stark.info.

But when I see with block " Demonstrate block regions (Custom_stark) "

i can see only in this default format.
[image]

And how can i get the triptych in desired format mention in below image

[image]

And below is the code for page.tpl.php

```
<?php if ($page['triptych_first'] || $page['triptych_middle'] || $page['triptych_last']): ?>
    <div id="triptych-wrapper"><div id="triptych" class="clearfix">
      <?php print render($page['triptych_first']); ?>      
  <?php print render($page['triptych_middle']); ?>
  <?php print render($page['triptych_last']); ?>
</div></div> <!-- /#triptych, /#triptych-wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 <?php if ($page['triptych_first'] || $page['triptych_middle'] || $page['triptych_last']): ?>
   <div id="triptych-wrapper">
      <div id="triptych" class="clearfix">
         <div style="float: left; width: 25%;">
            <?php print render($page['triptych_first']); ?>      
         </div>
         <div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
            <?php print render($page['triptych_middle']); ?>
         </div>
         <div style="float: right; width: 25%;">
            <?php print render($page['triptych_last']); ?>
         </div>
         <div style="clear: both;"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: I modified the code as mention, and i believe this div's not gonna be off exact size. The triptych_middle takes area of 50% which is larger than other two. And i manually changes the value but could not get the divs in above format...